# mysql_upgrade on fresh MySQL/MariaDB installation

Tags: mysql, mariadb, upgrade

What I've noticed lately is that whenever I install MariaDB or MySQL on a clean machine, and if I run mysql_upgrade it does the upgrading, so I figured since it's not showing it's already upgraded, I should do it.
So, it's been my practice ever since. Does anyone know anything more about this? Why this isn't done during installation process? Does this mean newer mariadb/MySQL server comes with table from older version?

Comment: a clean MySQL/MariaDB install should not need mysql_upgrade to be run during initial setup unless you restored a backup from an old version and that backup includes mysql system tables.

Comment: Understandable, but the question is why does it do any work then? Why doesn't it say "already upgraded" like it does when you run it after upgrade for the second time?
I asked an MySQL expert and he answered me so I'll post an answer

Comment: `mysql_upgrade also saves the MySQL version number in a file named mysql_upgrade_info in the data directory. This is used to quickly check whether all tables have been checked for this release so that table-checking can be skipped.`
this file is not present during initial installation hence when you run mysql_upgrade it will not tell you that there is no need for it on a fresh install

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Bogdan Kecman](https://www.linkedin.com/in/bogdan) who worked at Oracle:

> `mysql_upgrade` checks whether the tables are at the latest version, if not - upgrades them
>   and then marks them as upgraded. On a fresh install, even though tables are on the latest version, they are not marked. So, `mysql_upgrade` marks them. It does nothing else. To avoid scanning them
>   again when `mysql_upgrade` runs.

Sorry for lousy translation.